# PowerShell Extension : error running a script with import a cmdlet build in .net and works in standard pwsh session . Why?

Tags: powershell, vscode-extensions

we have develop a cmdlet in .Net, we import the module in the script, when we run/start it in powershell extension : ERROR
| Method 'AsPages' in type 'FuncAsyncPageable`1' from assembly 'Azure.Data.AppConfiguration, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' does not have an implementation.

when we run the same script in a standard pwsh session : IT WORKS

What need to be done to make it works and able to debug my PowerShell script in Vscode with this cmdlet imported ?

thanks

the expect return value of the call of this :
Add-Platform -Street "US" -GlobalCustomerCode "CUST1"   -Key "CompanyCode" -Value "CUST1"

is a json:
{"Id":135,"Street":"US","Environment":null,"GlobalCustomerCode":"CUST1","LocalCustomerCode":null,"Prefix":null,"Key":"CompanyCode","Value":"CUST1","LastUpdate":"2023-04-27T13:58:09.7374123Z"}